I am trying to save Cookie in my client-side browser in mern
Frontend:
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { BlogsUserStore } from "../store/blogs-user-store";

const Signin = () => {
  const oldEmail = useRef("");
  const oldPassword = useRef("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setUser, notifySuccess, notifyError, api } =
    useContext(BlogsUserStore);

  console.log(api);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = oldEmail.current.value;
    const password = oldPassword.current.value;
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${api}/api/user/signin`,
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
        {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      setUser([]);
      notifySuccess("Login Successful");
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing in:", error);

      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        notifyError(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        notifyError("Incorrect Password");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mt-4">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              name="email"
              id="email"
              ref={oldEmail}
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            />
            <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
              We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              name="password"
              id="password"
              ref={oldPassword}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Signin;

Backend
router.post(
    "/signin",
    checkForAuthenticationCookie("token", "home"),
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = req.body;
            const token = await User.matchPasswordAndGenerateToken(
                email,
                password
            );
            // console.log(token);
            res.cookie("token", token, {
                httpOnly: true, // Helps prevent XSS attacks
                maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", // Ensure cookies are sent over HTTPS
                sameSite:
                    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "None" : "Lax",
            });
            console.log(process.env);
            res.status(200).json({ message: "Signin successful" });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error during sign-in:", error);
            if (
                error.message === "User not found" ||
                error.message === "Incorrect password"
            ) {
                res.status(401).json({ message: error.message });
            } else {
                res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
            }
        }
    }
);

I am using this in my React. Whenever i signin it doesn't save my cookie to my client-side browser, i have used postman and it's correctly sending me cookie but when i am deploying in netlify it doesn't. The main problem i am getting is cookie is not getting saved in my browser
I have used withCredentials and samesite, secure logics. And it has been sending my data into postman but not getting saved browser so that i can use it for storing data

Your axios.post call has withCredentials in the wrong place. It should be inside the config object along with headers.
Maybe this is the problem OR

the httpOnly cuz cookies with the secure attribute will
not be set on HTTP connections.

like this:
  const response = await axios.post(
      `${api}/api/user/signin`,
      { email, password },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );


Yes it worked, but it still it's not saving my cookie. Finally Someone told me to use localstorage as alternative so i am using that. This is very confusing and deep, i think i have to use NextJS for this cookie feature...
Thanks for helping me out
